# Paste all text from a page Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Python3 with a Selenium driver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
try:
    driver.get("https://maclab.gameful.me/signin")
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nsl-button-google").click()
    email = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
    email.send_keys("338907@guhsd.net")
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password.send_keys("NotActualPassword")
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
except:
    print("Something went wrong!", sys.exc_info())
finally:
    driver.close()
    sys.exit()
```

My question is how to do a print the entire webpage that Selenium sees just as text in like a print() statement for the sake of debugging?

Comment: Are you asking if you can print the visible text of the page, or all of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium's method is `driver.page_source`. Just print that.

If you want to find all the text on the page, you'll want to get a list of all the elements on the page and then call the `.text` method on them. I think you could probably do that using an XPath query. Here's a one-liner.

```
all_text = [element.text for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("*") if element.text]
```

Explanation:

`all_text` will be a list of strings.

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` returns a list of all elements matching the XPath query.

`*` is a wildcard in XPath. You could probably also do `//*`, where `//` means "all matching nodes in the current node", since your current node is the root node.

Some elements that are found will not contain any text, (in which case `element.text` will return `None`), so you'll want to filter those out (`if element.text` in the list comprehension)

Comment: This will print all of the HTML. I wonder if they want the *visible* text though.

Comment: I take your point but they did ask for "the entire webpage that Selenium sees." I figure they want to see the source so they can make sure they're coding against the correct HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for the visible text but HTML will do too. If anyone knows how to do visible text that would be great too since it's less to look through than HTML.

Comment: @Badflar I've updated my answer to include getting just the text.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic Thanks!